# How to correctly include the right columns in a SQL index

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am struggling to get the correct index for a small query I want to run.  I was wondering if anyone had any tips for this kind of query?

My table columns are:

```
Id int (not used in query) PK
DateField datetime
IntField1 int
IntField2 int
IntField3 int
IntField4 int
IntField5 int (Not used in query)
IntField6 int (Not used in query)
```

My query looks like this

```
DECLARE @datefield datetime = '2019-01-01';
DECLARE @intfield1 int 1;
DECLARE @intfield2 int 2;

SELECT
SUM([sum])
FROM table1
WHERE 
DATEPART(YEAR, [DateField]) = DATEPART(YEAR, @datefield)
AND DATEPART(MONTH, [DateField]) = DATEPART(MONTH, @datefield)
AND [IntField1] = @intfield1
AND [IntField2] = @intfield2
AND [IntField3] = [IntField4]
```

The best index I have found on the execution plan is one that looks like this

```
CREATE INDEX idx_test_1 ON table1([DateField], [IntField1])
```

I have also tried something like this...

```
CREATE INDEX idx_test_2 ON table1([DateField], [IntField1], [IntField2], [IntField3], [IntField4])
```

But this turned out worse in the execution plan

I've been trying to follow this guide, but any other help would be appreciated.

https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-index-design-basics-and-guidelines/

Here is the execution plan for the query

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SyW3LQk5r

Comment: With questions on indexing, it's almost always a good idea to post the output of your various iterations using Brent Ozar's [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/). It'll help the helpers a lot!

Comment: Thanks, i've added the execution plan

Comment: As a rule functions applied to column values in a `where` clause preclude using an index _seek_. If you changed the query to check for a range of dates, i.e. `where DateField >= @StartDate and DateField < DateAdd( month, 1, @StartDate ) and ...` then it could benefit from an index.

Comment: Aside: The guide you cited doesn't appear to mention [included columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-indexes-with-included-columns?view=sql-server-ver15), i.e. columns that are stored in the index, but are nonkey columns. They are helpful in creating a [covering index](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function on the [DFateField] makes the index useless. You need to change the condition:

```
DATEPART(YEAR, [DateField]) = DATEPART(YEAR, @datefield)
AND DATEPART(MONTH, [DateField]) = DATEPART(MONTH, @datefield)
```

You need to rewrite your query to compare the field [DateField] direct with the parameters.

Both indexes should work. But depends on the selectivity, test1 index may be good enough.

You can calculate the date range for the month:

```
DECLARE @start_month date;
DECLARE @end_month date;

SET @start_month=DATEADD(DAY,1-DATEPART(DAY, @datefield),@datefield);
SET @end_month=DATEADD(MONTH,1,@start_month);
```

Then change the above condition to:

```
[DateField] >= @start_month  AND [DateField] < @end_month
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand how I can rewrite this logic to compare datefield directly as I only want to match on year/month?

Comment: added the rewriting of the condition in the answer